# Treat an XML file as database for a static web

Tags: html, xml, database, static-html

I want to make a static web without mariadb and php, as it states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201594/5250744) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158750/5250744) it's a bad idea to treat an XML file as a database.

But I think what I am going to do is not *really* a database, it's just to read and overwrite a pageview counter, **the file only for one line code** that only contain a number such as `<pageview>2</pageview>`.

**Edit :** This is intended so my visitors could also see the statistic of the page.

1. From the security and performance perspective is that save to do it with an XML file (around 200 site pages and 200 XML files for each page, the pageview for the site could be around 100K/day)?
2. Is there any alternative for this without making my site dynamic?

Comment: How do you intend to save the file without using a script of some description?

Comment: could jQuery help? but I think it's out of the question for now

Comment: You want stuff saves on the server. I take it from your comment you do not know what JQuery is

Comment: So, a pageview counter cannot be done without making my site dynamic?

Comment: You can get Google to do the counting for you. Is that what you mean? Alternatively use the web servers logs files.

Comment: No, I mean I want to show the pageview on the page also, so visitors could also view the counter

Comment: You need a script of some description to do this

Comment: This is obviously cannot be done without dynamically interacting with the server, I think cookie is not the answer either.. What was I thinking! Thanks Ed!

Comment: With the name John Smith probably a pint of bitter - http://www.johnsmiths.co.uk/